# DolphinDB: In grouped aggregation, how to get the last item of each row in an array vector column or aggregate an array vector column into a row?

Tags: arrays, dolphindb

I want to select the last item from the “BuyPrice“ column using the query `select last(BuyPrice) from t1 group by interval(Tradetime,15s, ‘prev')`. However, an error occurs if “BuyPrice“ is an array vector column. This issue can be solved with the script `select toArray(BuyPrice) from t1 group by interval(Tradetime,15s,'prev')`, but this solution fails when dealing with array vectors with varying lengths across rows.

Answer (score 0):

Cause: The array vector in your script contains missing values. The `interval` function specifies parameter fill as “prev“, which calls the `ffill` function and fills the missing values in the array vector with the previous non-NULL value. However, `ffill` does not support an array vector, that’s why an error occurs.

Solution: You can fill the missing values in the array vector with “0“ or other elements before calling the `interval` function. Here is an example script:

```
bid = array(DOUBLE[], 0, 20).append!([1.479 1.4787 1.4784 1.4667, 1.4796 1.479 1.4782 1.4781 1.4783, 1.4791 1.4785 1.4698 1.4720, 1.4699 1.469 1.4707 1.4704 1.4697, 1.4789 1.477 1.4780])
bidSize = array(INT[], 0, 20).append!([[], 100 200 200 300 0, 100 200 100 0, 0 100 200 0 300, 100 0 0])
TradeDate = 2022.01.01T10:00:00 + [1, 4, 12, 19, 21]
SecurityID = rand(`APPL`AMZN`IBM, 5)
t1 = table(SecurityID as `sid, TradeDate as `date, bid as `bid, bidSize as `bidSize)
tmp = exec bidSize from t1

bidSize1=each(def(mutable x)->iif(x.count()==0, [0], x), tmp)
newBidSize=array(INT[]).append!(bidSize1)

update t1 set bidSize=newBidSize
```